# Necessary and sufficient condition on whether there exists a multiple satisfying sum of integers property

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers,
give a necessary and sufficient condition on $b$ so that there exists an integer $k$ such that $S(ka)=b$
where $S(x):=$ the sum of digits of $x$ in base $10$

Comment: What have you tried and where did you find this problem? If you list your attempts in the question we will be better able to help you.

Comment: I've tried using congruence modulo $9$ because $S(x)=x[9]$ for all $x$ but it wasn't enouph